# How can I replace a specific text in string python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I'm confused when trying to replace specific text in python

my code is:

```
Image = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg"
Image2 = Image.replace("-1", "_s", 1)
print(Image)
print(Image2)
```

Output:

```
/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg
/home/user/Picture/Image_s.jpg
```

The output what I want from Image2 is:
**/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg**

Comment: That's not how you share images. You have to upload them. But you shouldn't post images of text, here, according to the [ask] page. If you can post it as text, post it as text.

Comment: `'_s.'.join(Image.rsplit('.'))`

Comment: @Chris Is my bot broken? Huh? I was pointing out how pasting "/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg" is not going to share that image to us. What bot are you talking about? You think I use a bot to write my messages? Not true. I'd ask you the same thing since it doesn't seem like you read the post to see what I was talking about.

Comment: @RandomDavis I'm only kidding.  The guy meant to paste urls, not images so your comment looked funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace` function **replaces** `"-1"` with `"_s"`.

If you want the output to be: `/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg`

You should replace `"-1"` with `"-1_s"`.

Try:

```py
Image = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg"
Image2 = Image.replace("-1", "-1_s")
print(Image)
print(Image2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are replacing the `-1` with `_s`

If you want to keep the -1 as well, you can just add it in the replacement

```
Image = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg"
Image2 = Image.replace("-1", "-1_s", 1)
print(Image)
print(Image2)
```

Output

```
/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg
/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg
```

---

If the digits can be variable, you can also use a pattern with for example 2 capture groups, and then use those capture groups in the replacement with `_s` in between

```
import re

pattern = r"(/home/user/Picture/Image-\d+)(\.jpg)\b"
s = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg\n/home/user/Picture/Image-2.jpg"

print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1_s\2", s))
```

Output

```
/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg
/home/user/Picture/Image-2_s.jpg
```

Or for example only taking the `/Image-` into account and then use the full match in the replacement instead of using capture groups:

```
import re

pattern = r"/Image-\d+(?=\.jpg)\b"
s = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg\n/home/user/Picture/Image-2.jpg"
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\g<0>_s", s))
```

Output

```
/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg
/home/user/Picture/Image-2_s.jpg
```

Comment: How if i have another image and not "1"

Comment: @VargaIgnacio I have added an example using a pattern where the numbers are variable.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the code you wrote is working as I would have expected from reading it. Now, as to how to correct it to do what you expected/wanted it to do is a little different. You don't necessarily need to replace here, instead, you can consider appending what you need, as it seems from the behaviour you are looking for is in fact appending something to the end of the path before the extension.

We can try to help the code a bit by making it a little more "generic" by allowing us to simply "append" anything to the end of a string. The steps we can do to achieve this is (for other readers, yes there are **more** foolproof ways to do this, for now sticking to a simple example) :

- split the string at `.` so that you end up with a list containing:

`["/home/user/Picture/Image-1", "jpg"]`

- Append to the first element what you need to the end of the string so you end up with:

`"/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s"`

- Use `join` to re-craft your string, but use `.`:

`".".join(["/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s", "jpg"])`

- You will finally get:

`/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg`

Coding the above, we can have it work as follows:

```
>>> Image1 = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg"
>>> img_split = Image1.split(".")
>>> img_split
['/home/user/Picture/Image-1', 'jpg']
>>> img_split[0] = img_split[0] + "_s"
>>> img_split
['/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s', 'jpg']
>>> final_path = ".".join(img_split)
>>> final_path
'/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg'
```

More idiomatic approach using Python's `pathlib` module is an interesting solution too.

```
from pathlib import Path

Image1 = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg"
p = Path(Image1)

# you have access to all the parts you need. Like the path to the file:
p.parent # outputs PosixPath('/home/user/Picture/')

# The name of the file without extension
p.stem # outputs 'Image-1'

# The extension of the file
p.suffix # outputs '.jpg'

# Finally, we get to now rename it using the rename method!

p.rename(p.parent / f"{p.stem}_s{p.suffix}")

# This will now result in the following object with renamed file!
# PosixPath('/home/user/Picture/Image-1_s.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

i think you should append the string in a certain position not replace

```
Image = "/home/user/Picture/Image-1.jpg"
Image2 = Image[:26]+ '_s' + Image[26:]
print(Image2)
```

The output

[image]

Comment: how if the image address is not 26 letter?? apologize my questions is not spesific

Comment: you can replace it, according to the number of letters you will add

Comment: `Image2 = '_s.'.join(Image.split('.'))` or `Image2 = '_s.'.join(Image.rsplit('.'))`  is more convenient